# How to send a single string to python function from ajax query

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, ajax

Context: I am using JavaScript to send a string as a parameter to a python function over the flask.
But I always get "the missing 1 parameter error" on the python side.

This is what my Ajax query looks like:

```
$.ajax({
      url : 'ListMaker',
      data: 'Q1',
      success: function(data) {
       //does something 
      }
      });
```

This is what my python function looks like:

```
@app.route("/ListMaker",methods=["POST","GET"])
def ListMaker(text):
    #make it a string just incase
    quarter=str(text)
    
    //do things with string
```

Any other similar questions I can find online, only talk about issues with Ajax and don't really cover the python side. In my case, the function is clearly being called, but it claims to receive no data to work with.

Am I sending the data wrongly from the Ajax side? Or am I parsing it wrongly on the python side?

---

Clarification for `NoneType` error from the comments below:

I am sending over:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"letter": "Q", "value": "25%"})
```

I am receiving it on the python side like so:

```
data=request.get_json()
letter=data["letter"]
value=data["value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in a Flask route are for variables in the path, called "[variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)" in Flask:

```
@app.route("/ListMaker/<text>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def ListMaker(text):
    ...
```

As jQuery Ajax requests are GET by default, your data will be converted to a query string, in this case `/ListMaker?Q1`. You can access the query string in Flask with [`flask.request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args).

However, query strings are key-value, and you are only supplying a key, which will correspond to the Python dict `{'Q1': ''}`. You should either set the Ajax data to a string like `quarter=Q1`, or use an object:

```
$.ajax({
      url : 'ListMaker',
      data: {'quarter': 'Q1'},  // or 'quarter=Q1'
      success: function(data) {
       //does something 
      }
      });
```

Then you will be able to access it in Flask:

```
@app.route("/ListMaker", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def ListMaker():  # no parameters needed
    quarter = flask.request.args["quarter"]
    # quarter == "Q1"
```

If you want to use a POST request, set `method: 'POST'` in the Ajax-call, and use [`flask.request.get_data()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_data) or [`flask.request.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json) on the Flask side.

Comment: Hi Rupus! Thank you for your detailed explanation! I followed your method for GET and later tried it for POST. Both result in the same error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. It claims to be reading a None object but I know for a fact I am sending over a string, how do I work around this?

Comment: What are you sending (the 'data' in the ajax request) and how are you using it in Flask?

Comment: I have edited post to clarify what I am doing to get the NoneType error

Comment: Don't JSON.stringify the data, just give 'data' the object directly in the ajax request.

Comment: I removed the JSON.stringify and just passed this, `data: {"letter": "Q", "value": "25%"}`. same error still. 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.' this occurs at the line `letter=data["letter"]` in the python file